# How to unit test Akka.Net Actor State (using Become())

Tags: unit-testing, akka.net

I have an Actor and when it recieves a `StartMessage`, it should change state using `Become(Started)`. How do I unit test whether or not the Actor's state has changed to `Started()` ?

**MyActor class**

```cs
public class MyActor : ReceiveActor
{
    public MyActor()
    {
        Receive<StartMessage>(s => {
            Become(Started); // This is what I want to unit test
        });
    }

    private void Started()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Woo hoo! I'm started!");
    }
}
```

**Unit Test**

```cs
        [TestMethod]
    public void My_actor_changes_state_to_started()
    {
        // Arrange
        var actor = ActorOfAsTestActorRef<MyActor>(Props.Create(() => new MyActor()));

        // Act
        actor.Tell(new StartMessage());

        // Assert
        var actorsCurrentState = actor.UnderlyingActor.STATE; // <-- This doesn't work
        Assert.AreEqual(Started, actorsCurrentState);
    }
```

**UPDATE**

Related to the answer from tomliversidge: My reason for writing this unit test was academic but in reality, it's not a good unit test which is why you aren't able to do it as I'd hoped. From [Petabridge's Unit Testing Guide](https://petabridge.com/blog/how-to-unit-test-akkadotnet-actors-akka-testkit/):

> In reality, if one actor wants to know the internal state of another actor then it must send that actor a message. I recommend you follow the same pattern in your tests and don’t abuse the TestActorRef. Stick to the messaging model in your tests that you actually use in your application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would normal test this by message passing. For example, what messages do you process in the Started state? I'm presuming your example has been simplified to the Console.WriteLine action inside of Started.

If you send the StartMessage and then a second message that is processed when in the Started state you can then assert on a response to this second message.

As a simple suggestion:

```
private void Started()
{
    Receive<StartMessage>(msg => {
        Sender.Tell(new AlreadyStarted());
    } 
}
```

if StartMessage is received whilst in the Started state, you can then assert on receiving an AlreadyStarted message.

For more info check out the Petabridge article https://petabridge.com/blog/how-to-unit-test-akkadotnet-actors-akka-testkit/

Comment: I've read Petebridge's unit testing guide front to back a few times now :-) I'm going to update my question with some verbiage from it that supports your answer. I was hoping there'd be a different answer but I think you've confirm that a scenario where you're writing unit tests like this probably indicates code smell

Comment: Yeah best to stick to black box message passing :)